# make: how to append text to beginning and end of list?

Tags: linux, makefile

In the makefile I'm writing, I am using the shell command `find` to build a list of source files to compile. In particular, I'm using the line:

```
SRCS := $(shell find $(SOURCES) '*.[cs]')
```

Now this works just fine. However, I would like to add support for excluding files that have a pattern that appears in a list called `EXCLUDE`. I'd like to use the `prune` option of `find`.

Something like this works if there is only one item in `EXCLUDE`

```
SRCS := $(shell find $(SOURCES) -name ${EXCLUDE} -prune -o -name '*.[cs]' -print)
```

To make this work with multiple excludes, I need to repeat the `-name exclude -prune -o` for each element in the exclude list.

TLDR: I need a way to transform the list `EXCLUDE` which may for example be `a b c` into `-name a -prune -o name b -prune -o name c -prune -o`. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(patsubst %,-name % -prune -o,$(EXCLUDE))` should work.